# Importing from external C code doesn't work

Tags: python, c, gcc, cython

Basically I have pulled ONLY avscan sample from this GitHub reporsitory [avscan](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/filesys/miniFilter/avscan) and I want to redefine/copy & paste the code in the main function of the user mode and implement it in my Cython code as below.

**cythonmod.pyx**:

```
cdef extern from *:
    r"""
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fltUser.h>
    #include "..\\avscan\\user\\utility.h"
    #include "..\\avscan\\inc\\avlib.h"
    #include "..\\avscan\\user\\userscan.h"
    
    HRESULT UserScanInit(PUSER_SCAN_CONTEXT pContext);
    
    int usermodeDef(){
        printf("User mode connecting to kernel mode\n");
        UCHAR c;
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        USER_SCAN_CONTEXT userScanCtx = {0};
    
    
        hr = UserScanInit(&userScanCtx);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize user scan data\n");
            DisplayError( hr );
            return 255;
        }
        
        //
        //  Read user's input until it reads 'q'
        //
        
        for(;;) {
        
            printf("press 'q' to quit: ");
            c = (unsigned char) getchar();
            if (c == 'q') {
            
                break;
            }
        }
        
        //
        //  Finalize the scan thread contexts.
        //
    
        hr = UserScanFinalize(&userScanCtx);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to finalize the user scan data.\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
    """

    int usermodeDef()
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "cythonmod",
        sources=["cythonmod.pyx"],
        include_dirs=["../avscan/inc", "../avscan/user"],
        extra_compile_args=["-include", "../avscan/user/userscan.h"],
    ),
]

setup(
    name="avscanner",
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules),
    compiler_directives={'language_level': 3, "unraisable_tracebacks": True}
)
```

When I run setup.py here I get the error that `UserScanInit` is undefined.

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\commonmodules.o:commonmodules.c:(.text+0x75df5): undefin
ed reference to `UserScanInit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\commonmodules.o:commonmodules.c:(.text+0x75e1d): undefin
ed reference to `UserScanFinalize'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\commonmodules.o:commonmodules.c:(.text+0x75e5b): undefin
ed reference to `DisplayError'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

GCC options generated by setup.py:

```
gcc -mdll -O -Wall -I../avscan/inc -I../avscan/user -IC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -c cythonmod.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cythonmod.o -include ../avscan/user/userscan.h
```

I tried many other things, i.e. import `userscan.h` directly as `cdef extern` from `"../avscan/user/userscan.h"`: but still wasn't able to fix it.

How do I import external C code into cython's inline C?

Comment: You need to link the module to the library

Comment: @DavidW, link what module to what library and how do I link it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the definitions:

- `UserScanInit` is defined in [avscan/user/userscan.c](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/f28183b782d1f113492f6eea424172f2addaf565/filesys/miniFilter/avscan/user/userscan.c#L137-L158).
- `UserScanFinalize` is defined in [avscan/user/userscan.c](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/f28183b782d1f113492f6eea424172f2addaf565/filesys/miniFilter/avscan/user/userscan.c#L361-L385).
- `DisplayError` is defined in [avscan/user/utility.c](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/f28183b782d1f113492f6eea424172f2addaf565/filesys/miniFilter/avscan/user/utility.c#L25-L48).

You may want to `#include` these files or add them to `sources=[...]`.

Comment: now I am getting below error: ../avscan/user/userscan.c:76:46: error: 'FILTER_REPLY_HEADER' undeclared (first use in this function)
   76 | #define SCANNER_REPLY_MESSAGE_SIZE   (sizeof(FILTER_REPLY_HEADER) + sizeof(ULONG))

Comment: If you are not able to figure it out, then ask a separate question on stackoverflow.com. My general advice to you is to make it work in C only, and only then make it callable from Python using Cython. To get more useful help, you need to explain in your question what *it works* means for you, i.e. what you are trying to accomplish, what makes you believe that *avscan* can help you, what makes you believe that you are using *avscan* correctly, and what makes you believe that it is supposed to work at all.